# Is it technically possible to fine-tune stable diffusion (any checkpoint) on a GPU with 8GB VRAM

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, stable-diffusion

i am currently playing around with some generative models, such as stable-diffusion and i was wondering if it is technically possible and actually sensible to fine-tune the model on a Geforce RTX3070 with 8GB VRAM. Its just to play around a bit so small dataset and i dont expect good results out of it, but to my understanding if i turn down the batch size far enough and use lower resolution images it should be technically possible. Or am i missing something because on their repository they say that you need a GPU with at least 24GB.

I did not get to coding yet because i wanted to first check if its even possible before i end up setting everything up and then find out it does not work.

Comment: Which repository are you trying to use? Without knowing the model size it's relatively difficult to say yes or no.

Answer (score 1):

I've read about a person that was able to train using 12GB of ram, using the instructions in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7bVZDeGPv6I&ab_channel=NerdyRodent

It sounds a bit painful though. You would definitely want to try using the

```
--xformers
```

and

```
--lowvram
```

command line arguments when you startup SD. I would love to hear how this turns out and if you get it working.

Comment: Unfortunately i wasn't able to run it locally, but i did not try too long and instead switched to fine tuning my model with a colab notebook which worked quite well. But thanks for the response